# how to get the executed result link from javascript code

Tags: javascript, php

i am using aviary photo editor and when someone finish editing and click on save so i want to get the link of saved image when onsave function get executed and want to get the new generated image link in the input field as :

```
<html>
<body onSave="autofill();">
<input type="text" name="name_textbox" id="id_textbox" />   
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function autofill(){
    var object = document.getElementsByName('name_textbox');
    object.item(0).value="Autofill successful.";    
}</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the aviary photo editor code onsave function code :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>var featherEditor = new Aviary.Feather({
   apiKey: 'ceegvx4siylhayrr',
   apiVersion: 3,
   theme: 'dark', // Check out our new 'light' and 'dark' themes!
   tools: 'all',
   appendTo: '',
   onSave: function(imageID, newURL) {
       var img = document.getElementById(imageID);
       img.src = newURL;
   },
   onError: function(errorObj) {
       alert(errorObj.message);
   }
});
function launchEditor(id, src) {
   featherEditor.launch({
       image: id,
       url: src
   });
  return false;
}
</script>

<div id='injection_site'></div>
<img id='image1' src='http://images.aviary.com/imagesv5/feather_default.jpg'/>
<!-- Add an edit button, passing the HTML id of the image and the public URL of the image->
<p><input type='image' src='http://images.aviary.com/images/edit-photo.png' value='Edit    photo' onclick="return launchEditor('image1', 'http://images.aviary.com/imagesv5/feather_default.jpg');" /></p>
```

Comment: waiting for your replies...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you mean you want to add the new image url to value of input field, then do like:

```
..
onSave: function(imageID, newURL) {
   var img = document.getElementById(imageID);
   img.src = newURL;
   document.getElementById('your_input_field_id').value = newURL;
}
```

or if you want to change the image source:

```
..
onSave: function(imageID, newURL) {
   var img = document.getElementById(imageID);
   img.src = newURL;
   document.getElementById('image1').src = newURL;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply...but again i did it right but now one thing more i am getting the newURL in input field but now want to transfer this input value to another page as contact.php to post their in another input field through a href or submit ..! using php or javascript

Comment: if you have the value in input field, then on post submit you can get in on server side and pass to your required page accordingly

Comment: great...but one thing more i can do that but how to get the $result in input value field?